# Problem with 3 or more level of tree-view UI on Mobile

Tags: mobile, tree, collapsible-panels

I had come with a problem with review/summary screen on phone that requires the information to have 3-5 level of tree-view. Generally on mobile phone UI, nested information will be shown on another screen but because this is a review/summary screen that user will be able to review without any information hidden on another screen (user might miss it)

Any good suggestion for a design pattern for this? I find accordion gets too complicated and traditional tree view indentation limits horizontal space.

Comment: Can you show us pictures of what you have designed so far?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the suggestion that you should post where you are so far. It might reveal more of the parameters you're working within.

Here's a quick screenshot I just made in  Evernote:

[image: Evernote screenshot as an example]

Maybe it won't make designers swoon, but no one is going to mistake the information for anything but a 5-level taxonomy.

What's the "job" you're designing this to do? Without knowing more I would also encourage you (if you haven't already done so) to question how much really needs to be supported on mobile. How robust does it need to be? Is it a stock trading app, where critical business decisions may be executed with the mobile phone? Is it somehow critical to the experience to show five levels of hierarchy in one screen?